# How to rotate a redirected log

Tags: unix, io-redirection, logrotate

I am running my application in Ubuntu 16.04. I do not have the logs for my application redirected to a file yet. It logs out to the console when I run it. I do preserve the logs using redirection `>` to a file.
But its becoming quite heavy with time.

I need to rotate the logs for which I tried using `logrotate`. But it does not rotate my logs. Below is a snippet from my logrotate config file -

```
/home/rranjan/my-app/logs/log {
     su rranjan rranjan
     missingok
     size 100k
     hourly
     create 0660 rranjan rranjan
     rotate 20
 }
```

I had tried truncating the file as well but failed. I am not sure but is it that in case of redirection, the file handle would never be released?

How do I get my logs rolling?

Comment: What is the access right of the file `log` to which you output the logs?

Comment: Provided you set up your conf. in the standard place (`/ect/logrotate.con`), what does the `sudo logrotate /etc/logrotate.conf --debug` command says?

Comment: I did try with the default config but same results. things work fine when I test with any normal file updating it myself. Its only after redirection(>) that the file fails to roll.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of *redirecting*, you should use **piping** trough the [`logger`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/logger)  command.

```
<your_script> | logger -p /home/rranjan/my-app/logs/log
```

Then if this is not enough, maybe try asking it on https://superuser.com/

I found [that one interesting for you](https://superuser.com/questions/291368/log-rotation-of-stdout).

Comment: `logger` doesn't seem to be working for me. I tried `-f` flag as well. Doesn't write to the file at all